# Floating Button doesn't change background image on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating my first custom audio player - i'm pretty new to WebDesign -
I have my Play button shown when the page loads
When i click the playbtn it dissapears, the track plays, i can stop it by clicking on the same spot where the playbtn was before, and the track stops but still no picture,
so my audio simply doesnt load the backgroungImage of my Javascript code! even that the rest of the code works!

**JavaScript**

```
// vars
var my_track, playbtn, mutebtn, currentTime, duration, barSize, bar, progressBar ;


// Set object references
my_track = document.getElementById('my_track');
playbtn = document.getElementById('playbtn');
mutebtn = document.getElementById('mutebtn');
currentTime = document.getElementById('currentTime');
duration = document.getElementById('fullDuration');
barSize = 300 ;
bar = document.getElementById('defaultBar')
progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar')

//innerHTML

// Add Event Handling
playbtn.addEventListener('click',playOrPause, false) ;
mutebtn.addEventListener('click',muteOrUnmute, false) ;
bar.addEventListener("click", clickedBar,false) ;
// event handling with function
my_track.addEventListener("timeupdate", function update() {
var curmins = Math.floor(my_track.currentTime / 60);
var cursecs = Math.floor(my_track.currentTime - curmins * 60);
var durmins = Math.floor(my_track.duration / 60);
var dursecs = Math.floor(my_track.duration - durmins * 60);
    if(cursecs < 10){ cursecs = "0"+cursecs; }
currentTime.innerHTML = curmins+":"+cursecs;
}, false); 

my_track.addEventListener("timeupdate", function progress(){
if (!my_track.ended){
    var size = parseInt(my_track.currentTime*barSize/my_track.duration);
    progressBar.style.width = size + "px";
}
else{
    currentTime.innerHTML = "0:00"
    playbtn.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../icon/audio_play.png")';
    playbtn.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    playbtn.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
    playbtn.style.backgroundSize = '25px 25px';
    progressBar.style.width = "0px" ;
    window.clearInterval(updateTime);
}
}, false);

// Functions
function playOrPause(){
if(!my_track.paused && !my_track.ended) {
    my_track.pause();
    playbtn.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../icon/audio_play.png")';
    playbtn.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    playbtn.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
    playbtn.style.backgroundSize = '35px 35px';
    window.clearInterval(updateTime);
}
else {
    my_track.play();
    playbtn.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../icon/audio_stop.png")';
    playbtn.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    playbtn.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
    playbtn.style.backgroundSize = '35px 35px';
}
}
function muteOrUnmute(){
if (my_track.muted == true ){
    my_track.muted = false ;
    mutebtn.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../icon/audio_speaker.png")';
    mutebtn.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    mutebtn.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
    mutebtn.style.backgroundSize = '25px 25px';
}
else {
    my_track.muted = true ;
    mutebtn.style.backgroundImage = 'url("../icon/audio_mute.png")';
    mutebtn.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    mutebtn.style.backgroundPosition = 'center';
    mutebtn.style.backgroundSize = '25px 25px';

}
}
function clickedBar(e){
if (!my_track.ended){
    var mouseX = e.pageX - bar.offsetLeft ;
    var newtime = mouseX*my_track.duration/barSize;

    my_track.currentTime = newtime ;
    progressBar.style.width = mouseX + 'px';
}
}
```

**CSS**

```
*{
margin: 0 ;
padding: 0 ;
}
html, body {
margin: 0 ;
padding: 0 ;
}
/*-------AUDIO STARTS HERE-----------*/

#audioplayer {
float: right ;
border: 2px solid #fff;
background-color: #515254;
width: 200px ;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
margin-top: -20px ;
margin-right: 8px ;
}
#audioplayer nav {
border-radius: 4px;
}
#defaultBar {
position: absolute ;
width: 196px ;
height: 8px ;
background-color: black ;
top: 0 ;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
#progressBar {
position: absolute ;
height: 8px ;
width: 0px ;
background-color: green ;
}
#beforebtn {
border: none ;
outline: none ;
height: 25px ;
width: 25px ;
background-image: url("../icon/before_track.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat ;
background-position: center ;
background-size: cover ;
margin-top: 6px ;
margin-left: 3px ;
float: left ;
cursor: pointer ;
}
#playbtn {
border: none ;
outline: none ;
height: 35px ;
width: 35px ;
background-image: url("../icon/audio_play.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat ;
background-position: center ;
background-size: cover ;
margin-left: 5px ;
margin-right: 5px ;
margin-top: 1px ;
float: left ;
cursor: pointer ;
}
#playtbn:target {
background-image: url("../icon/audio_stop.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat ;
background-position: center ;
background-size: cover ;
}
#nextbtn {
border: none ;
outline: none ;
height: 25px ;
width: 25px ;
background-image: url("../icon/next_track.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat ;
background-position: center ;
background-size: cover ;
float: left ;
margin-top: 6px ;
cursor: pointer ;
}
#mutebtn {
float: right ;
border: none ;
outline: none ;
height: 25px ;
width: 25px ;
background-image: url("../icon/audio_speaker.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat ;
background-position: center ;
background-size: cover ;
margin-top: 6px ;
margin-right: 3px ;
cursor: pointer ;
}
#audioplayer button {
background-color: #515254;
border-radius: 50% ;
}
#mutebtn:active, #playbtn:active , #beforebtn:active, #nextbtn:active {
position: relative ;
top: 2px ;
}

#timebox{
float: right ;
margin-top: 11px ;
margin-right: 5px ;
height: 16px ;
width: 38px ;
background-color: #515254 ;
color: #fff ;
border: 1px solid #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
}
#currentTime {
float: right ;
font-family: arial ;
font-size: 14px ;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ID="audioplayer">
        <audio ID="my_track">
            <source src="audio/take_me_baby.wav" type="audio/wav"/>
        </audio>
        <nav>
            <div ID="defaultBar">
                <div ID="progressBar"></div>
            </div>
            <div ID="buttons">
                <button ID="beforebtn"></button>
                <button ID="playbtn" class="playbtn"></button>
                <button ID="nextbtn"></button>
                <button ID="mutebtn"></button>
                <div ID="timebox">
                    <span ID="currentTime">0:00</span><span ID="fullDuration"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
<!-- @end audio tag -->
```

Hope this is clear for you guys :)
Thanks to all the help i can get!

Comment: That is **JAVASCRIPT** not **JAVA**. There is a **BIG** difference between both.

Comment: JavaScript is to Java, like PineApple is to Apple.

Comment: **-------BIG DIFFERENCE-------**

Comment: Java is software and Javascript is a web programming scripting language. Big difference. Uhhh -- the people who named javascript :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your icons are in the right folder.
2. You may need to wrap your code in a `window.onload`:

   window.onload = function() {
     //... your javascript
   };

http://plnkr.co/edit/kpU3oXNwhei5B6O9YKEO?p=preview

Comment: thanks Clint Powell - it doesn't work for me doe :/
Sorry to all the people who feel offended i surely ment Javascript not Java...

Answer (score 0):

found the answer myself :)
changed my background-image from CSS to a normal  tag on my html

```
<button ID="playbtn" onclick='this.firstChild.src="icon/audio_stop.png"'>
<img src="icon/audio_play.png"/>
</button>
```

and some changes on the javascript as followed:

```
function playOrPause(){
console.log(5);
if(!my_track.paused && !my_track.ended) { 
my_track.pause();
playbtn.firstChild.src = "icon/audio_play.png";
window.clearInterval(updateTime);
}
else {
my_track.play();
playbtn.firstChild.src = "icon/audio_stop.png";
}
}
```

much shorter and it even works :)
btw this: "window.onload = function() { //... your javascript };"
used to help aswell :) so thanks again Clint Powell !!